# why does this only work on localhost

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, login-control

**Never Mind it's working now (have no idea why but that's ok), and thank you everybody for your help**

i have written a code that login users by email instead of username here it is :

```
 protected void eLogin(object sender, EventArgs e) //allowing users to login with email
{
    string uid = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(mainLogin.UserName);
    mainLogin.UserName = null;
    mainLogin.UserName = uid;
}
```

and here is the login control:

```
<asp:Login ID="mainLogin" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
    RememberMeText="Remember me" TitleText="" 
    DestinationPageUrl="~/RedirectPage.aspx" 
    OnLoggingIn="eLogin"
     >
    <CheckBoxStyle CssClass="remBox" />
    <LoginButtonStyle CssClass="loginButton" />
    <TextBoxStyle CssClass="loginTextBox" />
</asp:Login>
```

but it will only work on localhost and not the actual hosting.
*here is what goes wrong :Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.*

i am using asp.net 3.5, thanks in advance

Comment: You question is badly structured. What exactly is not working on actual hosting?

Comment: Are you sure that the user you are logging in as exists in both environments?

Comment: If you've found the solution and it's *not* one of the existing answers, post it yourself and then accept it rather than adding `[solved]` to the title.

Comment: @wahtever - the convention on this site for when you have solved your issue is to *accept* the answer which solved the issue, or choose the best among those which did. A question with an accepted answer shows up clearly marked as such by its color-coding.

Comment: @ChrisF - you beat me by four seconds!

Comment: @Andrew - your explanation is good too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not post your error, I can only guess that your `Membership.GetUserNameByEmail` is failing.  Either your connection to a database is failing, or the user does not exist in the database to which you are connecting.

Comment: the login fails _Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again_.

Comment: Does this help: http://forums.asp.net/t/959371.aspx/1?Your+login+attempt+was+not+successful+Please+try+again+

Comment: i am already using this :` <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="conn" providerName="host"/>
    </connectionStrings>`.

Comment: I presume 'conn' is something like: `Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD`.  You need to add logging.  Do you successfully connect to DB?  Is eLogin even called?  Does your user exist in the DB?

Comment: the database is tested and working, i can login with user name , but i cant with email on the host

Answer (score 0):

The user is logged in based on the result of the ValidateUser function in the membership provider, which if you are not using a custom membership provider is probably validating against the user name field.  It possible that in your testing environment the email you are using actually is the user name for some account and that is why it works in one place and not the other.

Comment: it's my own account i am using and i entered a different user name than the email (not the admin account. just one i created).